# Get Windows username containing non-english chars in c#

Tags: c#, windows, non-english

We use the code from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207506/logoff-interactive-users-in-windows-from-a-service) to get the name of the connected windows user in order to disconnect them.

In brief, GetUserName(), GetCurrentUserName(), LogOffUser() and LogOffCurrentUser(), as follows.

**THE PROBLEM:**
Under english version of Windows and when the username contains non-english characters, the user will not logoff.

After some debugging we found out that the username inside GetUserName() is displayed with question marks instead of the non-enlgish characters, but in LogOffCurrentUser() is displayed properly. So the user stays connected because the username cannot be found when attempting to disconnect.

Is there any way to solve this?

```
public static string GetUserName(int sessionId, IntPtr server)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint count = 0;
        string userName = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            WTSQuerySessionInformation(server, sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out buffer, out count);
            userName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer).ToUpper().Trim();
        }
        finally
        {
            WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        }
        return userName;
    }

//-------------------------------------

public static string GetCurrentUserName()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];

        string[] parts = username.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        if (parts[parts.Length - 1] == "SYSTEM") parts[parts.Length - 1] = "";
        return parts[parts.Length - 1];
    }

//-------------------------------------

public static bool LogOffUser(string userName, IntPtr server)
    {
        userName = userName.Trim().ToUpper();
        List<int> sessions = GetSessionIDs(server);
        Dictionary<string, int> userSessionDictionary = GetUserSessionDictionary(server, sessions);
        if (userSessionDictionary.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            return WTSLogoffSession(server, userSessionDictionary[userName], false);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

//-------------------------------------

public static void LogOffCurrentUser()
    {
        LogOffUser(GetCurrentUserName(), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION:**

When trying to fetch windows usernames that contain non-english (non-latin) characters you must p/invoke the unicode version of WTSQuerySessionInformation which is **WTSQuerySessionInformationW**.

Then the username can be placed to a string using **Marshal.PtrToStringUni** or **Marshal.PtrToStringAuto**.

In that way WTSLogoffSession will find the username in session dictionary and disconnect the user properly.